# Magento configurable product dropdown options duplicating

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, configurable-product

I have some configurable products for pots of paint, however, my dropdown options are duplicating for each available option.

For example;
I have various sizes of paint (750ml, 2L and 5L) and also various colours (Blue, Yellow, Green)
So, in full I have

- Blue 750ml, Blue 2L and Blue 5L
- Yellow 750ml, Yellow 2L and Yellow 5L
- Green 750ml, Green 2L and Green 5L

My options, should, be;

- Size: 750ml / 2L / 5L
- When selected, I should then be able to select a Colour from Blue / Yellow / Green

Unfortunately, these are the options that I'm getting in my dropdown select;

- 750ml / 750ml / 750ml / 2L / 2L / 2L / 5L / 5L / 5L
- When I select one of those, I only get 1 colour available in the colour option.

[image]

Edit:
I should also add that I don't have any plugins for the configurable products, and I get the same problem also on the default theme, so the problem isn't coding/template file related.

Edit 2: 
I've setup the attribute set, attributes and product on another website and it all works fine. So the issue is with a setting somewhere in this Magento store, however, I'm not sure what setting it is!

Comment: The problem is definitely in your admin panel settings, not the code. Unfortunately, can't tell for sure at the moment, but try to play with settings for some time. It is probably the way how you add options to your product and options configuration.

Comment: Been playing with the settings for a while, everything looks right - I'm stumped! I'll give it a break for now and have a look later with a clearer head!

Comment: Are the options duplicated in the admin when you go to the Manage Attributes section?